# Define own sort logic for some of columns

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have numeric and alphanumeric columns in the table. But when I sort by one of alphanumeric fields, I got incorrect sorting. For example:

```
4 Kb/s > 24 Kb/s
4 Kb/s > 2 Mb/s
```

I use automatic sorting of the table.

Comment: You should be able to define your own comparator to determine how those values should be sorted.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to change the type of the column. It looks like the data type of the column should be `Integer` or `Double` (or maybe just `Number`). Then it will sort correctly. You can use a `cellFactory` on the column to display the value with the units appended.

Comment: @James_D, can you answer to this question with `cellFactory` example of any `Integer Object.getValue()`? And with which parameter I should call `setCellValueFactory()` if property will be simple `Integer`? And last: `TableColumn<Object, Integer>` or `TableColumn<Object, String>` because it would show `Stirng`, but property is `Integer`. Thank you!

Comment: @James_D, sorry, I'm newbie in JavaFX and Java in general

Comment: Not really because I have no clue what you are actually doing: you haven't posted any code. The first type parameter in `TableColumn` is supposed to be the type of the item in each row, so it should be something more specific than `Object` (it should be the type of the things you pass to `table.getItems().add(...)`, and should be the same type as you declare for the `TableView`). Maybe see [this tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/)